# AG-Grid - How to refresh rows at top-level and group children level at the same time without resulting to purge?

Tags: ag-grid-angular

Currently i am building a project where i want to refresh the rows of my server-side-model ag grid **without purging** or **reloading the entire grid through setGridOptions()**  making them all to be reloaded. I am able to see my changes being refreshed at group children level, but not able to see my top-level changes being refreshed. Basically, i want to move a row to inside a row group and also remove it from inside the row group.

Does anybody have any tips how i should proceed?